# Perl: How to extract the range of lines starting from "IF" to "END-IF" ignoring the lines starting with a *

Tags: regex, perl

My code tries to extract the range even if the line starts with a * Here is my code:

```
while (<FILE1>) {

    $_ =~ s/^\s+//; #remove leading spaces
    $_ =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces

    if (/IF/ .. /END-IF/) {

        if($_ =~ m/END-IF/) {

            $flag = 1;
        }
        print FINAL "$_\n";

        if ($flag == 1) {

            $flag = 0;
            print FINAL "\n\n";
        }
    }
}
close FINAL;
close FILE1;
```

My FINAL output file should contain only the the ranges between all IF's and END-IF's seperated by \n\n  AND if there is an IF within an IF block, The range starting from the first if to the line before the second IF should be saved in FINAL seperated by \n\n

Comment: You haven't really described how your program is failing. Your starting regex requires `IF` to be preceded by a character other than '*' and a space. So `IF` can't be at the beginning of the line. Is that correct?

Comment: IF preceeded only with spaces. IF should be ignored in all other cases

Comment: Maybe you should use `/\bIF\b/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want IF and END-IF to be excluded,then use the below:

```
perl -lne 'if(/IF/.../END-IF/ and $_!~/^\*|IF|END-IF/){print}' your_file
```

if you want IF and END-IF to be included,then use the below:

```
perl -lne 'if(/IF/.../END-IF/ and $_!~/^\*/){print}' your_file
```

Comment: I have to stop the range Extraction if I encounter another IF within an IF and also seprate with a delimiter \n\n in my output file.

Answer (score 0):

Addition of the next line solved my problem :)

```
next if(/^\*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if ( /IF/ .. /END-IF/ ) {
        next if /^\*|IF|END-IF/;
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
This is a line.
And another line...
IF
1. A line within the if
* 2. An asterisk line within the if
3. And now, another line within the if
END-IF
Outside an if construct.
Still outside the if construct.
IF
4. A line within the if
* 5. An asterisk line within the if
6. And now, another line within the if
END-IF
```

Output:

```
1. A line within the if
3. And now, another line within the if
4. A line within the if
6. And now, another line within the if
```

Lines within the `IF .. END-IF` range are conditionally passed, then are printed only if they don't start with `*` or contain either `IF` or `END-IF`.